# What's the problem with the following Terraform AWS Role Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

```
data "aws_instances" "emr_cluster_ec2s" {
  filter {
    name = "key-name"
    values = ["linkedin-learning-emr-key"]
  }
}

data "aws_iam_role" "emr_instance_role" {
  name = "AmazonEMR-InstanceProfile-20230407T155038"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "emr_ec2_connect" {
  name = "ec2-connect"
  role = "${data.aws_iam_role.emr_instance_role.id}"

  policy = <<EOF
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": [
          "ec2-instance-connect:SendSSHPublicKey"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": ${jsonencode(data.aws_instances.emr_cluster_ec2s.ids)}
      },
      {
        "Action": [
          "ec2:DescribeInstances"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    }
  }
  EOF
}
```

When I execute the above aws role policy assignment, I get the following error:

```
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: "policy" contains an invalid JSON policy
│
│   with aws_iam_role_policy.emr_ec2_connect,
│   on ec2-connect.tf line 44, in resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "emr_ec2_connect":
│   44:   policy = <<EOF
│   45:   {
│   46:     "Version": "2012-10-17",
│   47:     "Statement": [
│   48:       {
│   49:         "Action": [
│   50:           "ec2-instance-connect:SendSSHPublicKey"
│   51:         ],
│   52:         "Effect": "Allow",
│   53:         "Resource": ${jsonencode(data.aws_instances.emr_cluster_ec2s.ids)}
│   54:       },
│   55:       {
│   56:         "Action": [
│   57:           "ec2:DescribeInstances"
│   58:         ],
│   59:         "Effect": "Allow",
│   60:         "Resource": "*"
│   61:       }
│   62:     }
│   63:   }
│   64:   EOF
```

I tried searching online and docs, but I couldn't find anything helpful. Please provide some insight if you're familiar with this.
According to the docs the `jsonencode(data.aws_instances.emr_cluster_ec2s.ids)` generates a tuple like `[X1,X2,X3]` which is exactly what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version `2023-04-08` is **invalid**. It [should be](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_version.html) `2012-10-17`. You have also **incorrect indentation** and missing `]`. So it should be:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "emr_ec2_connect" {
  name = "ec2-connect"
  role = "${data.aws_iam_role.emr_instance_role.id}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
    "Action": [
        "ec2-instance-connect:SendSSHPublicKey"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": ${jsonencode(data.aws_instances.emr_cluster_ec2s.ids)}
    },
    {
    "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeInstances"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. The issue still persists.

Comment: personally I would remove the jsonencode function in the middle of this and wrapp the whole thing in an jsonencode as then you get all the nice parsing from your IDE to catch errors like this in future.

Comment: OMG! The missing bracket resolved it. Thank you! I completely missed that.

Comment: The "Version" is the [version of the policy *language*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_version.html), not of the policy itself.  So the date needs to be one of the few that AWS accepts.  If you want to encode a policy version into the policy, use [the "Id" field](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_id.html).  You're **far** from the first person to make that mistake.